# PHP/MySQL/jQuery - Set textarea to new div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I currently have a textarea that will set the input. But I am trying to save the text entered to a database table, and output that text to a div below the textarea. I'm not the most efficient PHP programmer so I'm hoping someone can shed some light.

Here's what I have for markup and JS:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="top-box">Tell us what you're thinking...</div>

    <form method="post" action="#">
        <p>
            <label for="boxText">
                <textarea id="boxText"></textarea>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>

    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('textarea').bind('blur', function() {
    $(this).val(function( i, val ) {
      return val;
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to add a div after the `textarea` that contains the text from the `textarea`?

```
$('textarea').bind('blur', function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.after($("<div />").text($this.val()));
});
```

Did you want to clear the `textarea` afterward?

```
$('textarea').bind('blur', function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.after($("<div />").text($this.val()));
     $this.val('');
});
```

---

Also, this markup doesn't appear to be valid

```
<div id="top-box">Tell us what you're thinking...</p>
```

Comment: that does work in terms of creating a new div, however I need to save that input in the textarea, in the div that is created.  it still resets when I refresh the browser. that's why I think I need to write it to a db table. In addition, I'd need the texarea to reset to empty after submitting the input.

Comment: Oh, then yeah - you'll have to use some Ajax.  You'll need to create a PHP action and post to it, and then read that value back from the db when the page loads.

Comment: markup was my fault. forgot to change it. I have yet to really dive into AJAX and I'm not too experienced in php yet. this should be fun! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Where's your function for saving the text to the database? You can use AJAX to submit the form, and `echo json_encode($your_messages);` after your text has been put in the database. From there, in your AJAX success function, you can do whatever you want with that data.

Comment: I don't have a function set yet, because I'm not sure where to begin to save to the db. I've got some research to do, but I'll use your suggestions as a bit of a road map. thanks.